# Cannot create XML Schema collection for xml version 1.1 in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2

I can create the schema with xml version 1.0 but need to use xml version 1.1 for this project because some of the 1.1 features are needed (Extensibility, Keyrefs, Assertions). Anybody know if xml version 1.1 is compatible with SQL Server 2008 R2? I cannot find any specific answer to this question when searching online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only XML Schema 1.1 processors available, I believe, are Saxon, Xerces, and Altova.

It would be a little surprising if SQL Server 2008 supported XSD 1.1 since XSD 1.1 only came out in 2013.

But Microsoft gave up implementing new W3C XML specifications years ago: you have to go to third parties. Which isn't easy if you're locked into SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for this information! Now I have to figure out how to use one of these third party tools with Sql Server.